# Form not submitting into the database using Codeigniter_2.1.4 framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a form in Codeigniter but it does not to submit values to the database. I have tried to debug my code by echoing out "hello" in my method that works but the actual method does not submit anything to the database.

This is code in my view page

```
 <div data-role="content">
            <?php echo form_open('index.php/welcome/adduser'); ?>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">','</p>'); ?>
            <p>
            <label>Firstname: </label>
            <?php echo form_input('firstname', set_value( 'firstname' ) ); ?>

            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Lastname: </label>
            <?php echo form_input('lastname', set_value( 'lastname' ) ); ?>

        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Email: </label>
            <?php echo form_input('email', set_value( 'email' ) ); ?>

        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Age: </label>
            <?php echo form_input('age', set_value( 'age' ) ); ?>

        </p>
        <p>
            <label>username: </label>
            <?php echo form_input('username', set_value( 'username' ) ); ?>

        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password: </label>
            <?php echo form_input('password', set_value( 'password' ) ); ?>

        </p>

        <p>
            <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?>
        </p>  

    </div>
```

This is my controller

```
    <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    /** loading services* */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    /** loading several pages * */
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('abt-header');
        $this->load->view('abt-abovetheblues');
        $this->load->view('abt-footer');
    }

    public function adduser() {


        if ($this->_adduser_validate() === FALSE) {
            $this->index();
            return;
        }
        $data = new user();
        $data->firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');
        $data->lastname = $this->input->post('lastname');
        $data->username = $this->input->post('username');
        $data->password = $this->input->post('password');
        $data->email = $this->input->post('email');
        $data->age = $this->input->post('age');


        $this->load->view('#abt-profile');
    }

    private function _adduser_validate() {

        // validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Firstname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Lastname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[12]');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[12]');

//        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[password]');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'Age', 'required');

        return $this->form_validation->run();
    }



}

?>
```

Comment: `$daa`, `$u`, where are these defined? Where is the method `save()`? I don't see these anywhere.

Comment: You dont instantiate a model anywhere? I assume you are expecting `$u` to be the `User_model` and `$daa` is a typeo? So instantiate `$this->load->model('User_model', 'u');` in your constructor.

Comment: That was a typo error! I have pasted the correct code.. cheers

Comment: When you say User_model I am a bit confused as I have not put any code in the model

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying what data to be saved in which table.
Use something like this...

```
/*
$data = array(
    'tableCol1' => $this->input->post('postedItem1'),
    'tableCol2' => $this->input->post('postedItem2'),
   );
*/
$this->db->set($data); 
$this->db->insert($tableName);
```

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer when question is not clear ?

Comment: $this->db->insert('user') // my table name is user

Comment: #dianuj my question is my form does not submit values into the database using the code above.

Comment: I have added $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->insert("user", $data); to my controller but still not working

Comment: @Omade please have a look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert

Comment: Thanks dianuj the link was helpful! I was not passing my variable $data into my insert in the model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have not closed your form, add this to your view:

```
   <?php echo form_close();?>
```

I don't see where you have run your insert query which will insert data in database. Your Adduser function can be like this:

```
 public function adduser() {


    if ($this->_adduser_validate() === FALSE) {
        $this->index();
        return;
    }
    $data = array(
    'firstname' = $this->input->post('firstname'),
    'lastname' = $this->input->post('lastname'),
    'username' = $this->input->post('username'),
    'password' = $this->input->post('password'),
    'email' = $this->input->post('email'),
    'age' = $this->input->post('age'),
    );

    $this->db->insert('user',$data);
    $this->load->view('#abt-profile');
}
```

I am assuming you have set your database name and login credentials in config/database.php file
This will for sure help you. If there is any problem let me know.

Comment: Thanks! I got it sorted and like you asked where is my insert? I was actually not passing my variable $data into my insert in the model.